# changing background on mousemove

Tags: javascript, event-listener, mousemove

i can't change background here is my code

```js
const projectList = document.querySelector('.project-list');
projectList.addeventListener('mosemove', (e) => {
  projectList.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + e.offsetX + "," + e.offsetY + "40)";
})
```

```css
.project-list {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="project-list"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: You have several typing errors you can see in any debugger. Also, and more importantly, offsetX and offsetY will return values that can be way bigger than 255, so things like rgb(1145,989,745) will not produce valid colors. After fixing all the typos and restricting the values to be below 256, everything works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in the event name. It should be `mousemove` instead of `mosemove`. You also forgot a comma before the `40` value in the `rgb` function.

```
var projectList = document.querySelector('.project-list');
projectList.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    projectList.style.backgroundColor = "rgb("+e.offsetX+","+e.offsetY+",40)";
});
```

For a quick test this should work. But as already mentioned in the comments, this won't work well because `offsetX` and `offsetY` will produce values above `255`. You could use a remainder operator if you want to handle that (e.g., `offsetX % 255`).